# Trouble setting up an sftp chroot jail

Tags: ssh, chroot, sftp

I'm following the [SFTP chroot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot) wiki on ArchWiki and finding a huge snag: I can't get my `sftponly` users authorized.

#### Output of `tail -2 /etc/passwd` (my 2 users):

```
chris:x:1001:1002::/home/jail:/usr/bin/nologin
rick:x:1002:1002::/home/jail:/usr/bin/nologin
```

#### Output of `groups chris` and `groups rick`:

```
sftponly
```

#### The directory:

```
$ ls -l /home
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 3 root  root   4096 Jan  9 16:12 jail/

$ ls -l /home/jail
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 3 rick sftponly 4096 Jan  9 16:12 dropbox/
```

**note**: the only reason the `dropbox/` directory is owned by `rick` is because I was experimenting with changing ownership of files within the chroot jail directory because this was something I'd read about in my extensive googling. I would like the both `chris` and `rick` to be able to edit the same files. I will investigate facl permissions when I get to the point that I can even log them in.

#### The relevant section in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server

Match Group sftponly
  ChrootDirectory %h
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  AllowTcpForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
  PasswordAuthentication yes
```

#### From the log when I try to log in via `sftp rick@localhost` and enter the password:

```
Jan 09 16:44:17 dell-dropbox sshd[688]: Failed password for rick from ::1 port 57410 ssh2
Jan 09 16:44:23 dell-dropbox sshd[688]: Failed password for rick from ::1 port 57410 ssh2
Jan 09 16:44:28 dell-dropbox sshd[688]: Failed password for rick from ::1 port 57410 ssh2
Jan 09 16:44:29 dell-dropbox sshd[688]: Connection closed by authenticating user rick ::1 port 57410 [preauth]
```

**note**: They both have passwords set. I am typing in the password correctly. I can sftp in as myself without any problem.

What on earth am I missing?

Comment: I have the `Subsystem` line commented out and instead put the line: `Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp`, that works for me.

Comment: @RoVo I saw that in a couple of google results. My understanding is the `ForceCommand internal-sftp` overrides it for those accounts, but perhaps it doesn't work? I will try what you suggest. I'm curious if there's a security issue with it though, and if not, why Arch doesn't suggest it on the Wiki. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### WARNING: I am not  a security expert. I cannot ensure that it is impossible to login via ssh using this method, but it seems from my testing that you cannot.

The key problem seems to have been `/bin/nologin`, which turns out to have been unnecessary to begin with.

When sshd is configured with the above settings, and your users are set to have their home directories set to the jail like that, there is no way for them to ssh in anyway. Every tutorial I find on `chroot` jails with `ssh`, as opposed to tutorials about `chroot` jails and `sftp`, discusses the necessity of setting up system folders, essentially creating a system-within-a-system. Without them it seems to be impossible to log in via ssh *but not* via sftp.

So, follow my directions above, but don't set the user's shell to `/bin/nologin`. So far as I can tell, that's for daemon users.

Also, it's very easy to configure all this with ssh-keys. Simply having a root-owned `.ssh/authorized_keys` file in the shared home directory does the trick.

The result with a ssh-keys:

```
~ » ssh chriss@localhost                                                                                                                                                   
Enter passphrase for key '/home/malan/.ssh/id_rsa':
This service allows sftp connections only.
Connection to localhost closed.
```